# React styled-components style a dynamic component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a following problem:

I have defined some icons in my project. Each icon is defined by a component type (an icon from Material-UI) plus some additional props. I did it that way, so I can then render those icons in differing ways.

Anyway, let's say that I want to re-use the same icon in 2 places, but in one place I want it to be red, in the other I want it to be green. MUI icons don't accept a color prop (I mean not an RGB one, just a few predefined colors). So the way to do it is to style the icon component with css (`color:`).

I use `styled-components` so the way I would usually do this is:

```
const StyledIcon = styled(AssignmentIcon)`
  color: red
`
```

But the thing is, in some places I don't know which icon I'll be styling. For example some component may receive a list with `AssignmentIcon`s and `BugReportIcon`s. As it is with `styled-components`, I cannot define the styled components inside another component - so I cannot create a style like the one above, and just pass icons from the props to it.

I solved it like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-hofstadter-ww2ly. Basically, I have a `styleIcon` function, which takes a `React.ComponentType` (dynamically of course), puts in in `styled()` and returns it. This way I've applied some style to the icon and now I can render it.

My question is: this seems kinda sketchy, having some helper functions to do the job. Is there a simpler way to do it? (and by the way, I cannot use `style={{}}` props when rendering the icon - it may collide with other styles that I would apply via prop-spreading)

Answer (score 0):

Your component should always be able to switch to different color.

```
  const color = props => props.color || 'red'

  const StyledIcon = styled.div`
    color: ${color};
  `
```

If the `color` is given, then use `color`, ex.

```
  return <StyledIcon color="blue" />
```

I don't know if this solves your problem. Sometimes we want to use a theme mode, for example `StyledComponent` does support a theme.

https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced

Even when you don't want to always use one theme, you can apply different theme at run time.

```
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme1}>
    // A
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme2}>
      // B
      <Button>Themed</Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
    // C
  </ThemeProvider>
  // D
```

The locations A, B, C, D gets different themes:

- A. theme1
- B. theme2
- C. theme1
- D. defaultTheme

I believe the base solution should give u some ideas, but if not, try this sophisticated theme options offered by StyledComponent.

Comment: Yes, but you are missing an important fact, I am not trying to modify a div on the fly, I am trying to "attach" certain properties to a type/class. For example, I have a type `AssignmentIcon` from MUI. Or maybe `FooIcon` created by me. What I want to do is to be able to add some new properties to it on the fly/while rendering - without using `style` prop , using SC. What I did is when I receive a type like this and I have another like `StyledIcon` which contains a css style, I just write: `<StyledIcon as={icon} />` where icon is a dynamic variable. This way the css is applied to the `icon`

Comment: use `cloneElement` then, https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement. `cloneElement(render, { additionalProps })`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem, I assume that you want to change the color from Material UI without explicitly styling. So I came up with a wrapper that takes Material UI icons as one child node.

First, we need to create the styling for that wrapper:

```
const StyledIcon = styled.span<{color: string}>`
  svg, .icon {
    color: ${props => props.color}; // You can even pass a hex color
  }
`
```

Secondly, create a separate React component .You use can the styled one alone but this will help you with handling states and effects in the future:

```
interface ColorfulIconProps {
  color: string;

  [k: string]: any;
}

const ColorfulIcon: React.FC<ColorfulIconProps> = ({ color, children, ...rest }) => {
  // States and effects

  return (
    <StyledIcon color={color} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </StyledIcon>
  );
};
```

Finally, to use it, just simply pass any Material UI icons you want, or your own icon set as long as they're formatted in `svg`

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ColorfulIcon color="red">
      <AMaterialUIIcon />
    </ColorfulIcon>
  );
};
```

Live demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-brook-oecgn?file=/src/StyledIcon.tsx

Comment: Okay, this works, but see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69093656/react-styled-components-style-a-dynamic-component/69096125#comment122120540_69095432), I think this would be a simpler solution for me